# (EXCEL) How do I Compare 2 Columns and generate a PASS/FAIL rating based on the difference in values between the 2 Columns in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, countif

I am trying to compare the two columns in green. If the values in column labeled "C" are each within +/-0.01 of the values given in column labeled "C Assay", then I would like it to output a value of "PASS" to the cell next to "Accuracy", otherwise it would output "FAIL".

Example Image
[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy9eL.png)]

I managed to compare a single pair of values and output the expected results using this:

```
=IF(ABS(G91-H91)<0.01,"PASS","FAIL")
```

I just have no clue how to get it to iterate through each pair within the 2 columns to output a single "PASS/FAIL" if all the pairs do/don't meet the criteria above.

I tried using a few versions of this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(ABS((G91:G102)-(H91:H102)),<0.01),"PASS","FAIL")
```

But that didn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just drag your first formula down?

Comment: That would tell me whether each individual pair passes or fails. It must output a single "PASS" if all pairs pass or "FAIL" if even a single pair fails.

Comment: Then instead of "pass" and "Fail" put 1 or 0 and in another cell test for 0 in that column - no 0 then all pass...

Comment: That still doesn't work in my situation. I am trying to streamline the evaluation process for all of our spreadsheets that use this formatting. When these spreadsheets are generated, the formatting is locked such that only a small handful of cells are editable (we don't want other people to be able to edit these at all). It will absolutely not work if the formula would generate values in cells outside of the cells where editing is allowed. Changing these formatting conditions is also not an option.

Comment: `=IF(MAX(ABS(G91:G102-H91:H102))<0.01,"PASS","FAIL")`

Comment: Or to make it dynamic for varying number of data rows `=IF(MAX(ABS(FILTER(G:G,ISNUMBER(G:G))-FILTER(H:H,ISNUMBER(H:H))))<0.01,"PASS","FAIL")`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I made a fake dataset and added a helper column just for clarifications but you won't need it at all. The formula you need is:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS($C$2:$C$15-$B$2:$B$15)>0,01))=0;"PASS";"FAIL")
```

The tricky part here is using SUMPRODUCT combined with double unary operator to handle arrays. This is how it works:

1. Excel will first resolve this part: `ABS($C$2:$C$15-$B$2:$B$15)` it will get the absolute value of the differences based on C Assay and C. The out put of this part will be an array like the one shown in column named `just checking`
2. The previous step is trapped inside `--(step 1 formula) > 0`. This will check if any of the differences is higgher than 0.01 and will return `true/false`. But notice we are using double unary operator `--` so each boolean value will be converted into `1` if true, `0` if false.
3. Previous step is trapped into SUMPRODUCT. It will sum up all 1 and 0 from last step. Notice that if none of the differences is higher than 0.01, all outputs will be zero and then all summed up will be zero. If any difference is higher than 0.01, then the sum up will **not** be zero.
4. Now the final step is just use an IF to check if the final sum is zero or not, that means PASS/FAIL

You can see each step of how this works using the *Evaluate Formula* button on *Formula* tab. It's pretty interesting how Excel handles each single case.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(MAX(ABS(G91:G102-H91:H102))<0.01,"PASS","FAIL")
```

This worked great! Thanks Chris!